# Local Storage on Mobile phone using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, storage, dhtmlx

Can someone give me an example on how to use Phone's Local storage as Database instead of using MySQL server as database?

I am trying to use DHTMLX

Answer (score 0):

The default option would be to use the PhoneGap Storage API

[PhoneGap Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

This however is built on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C Web Storage API Specification, neither of which has been generally accepted by the community and as such is not supported across platforms.  It does however work on iOS and Android.

A more platform independent solution is Lawnchair.  It is a third party, open source, local JSON data store.

[Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/)

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage object can store data with no expiration and it will not be deleted when the browser is closed. It's pretty simple to use with plain JavaScript and may work in your situation. Here are really basic examples you could run without using any extra libraries.

```
// Create a localStorage object called user and store an object as a json string
localStorage.user = JSON.stringify({name: 'John Smith', age: 32, eyeColor: 'brown'});

// Create a localStorage object called cars and store some cars in there
localStorage.cars = JSON.stringify({
    0: {
        make: 'Honda',
        model: 'Fit',
        year: '2009'
    },
    1: {
        make: 'Ford',
        model: 'Mustang',
        year: '2002'
    }
});
```

You can then pull your data back out and into javascript objects for use in your app.

```
var cars = JSON.parse(localStorage.cars);
var mustang = cars[1];
console.log(mustang);
```

That should log your mustang object to the console.

There are probably a few security related things to think about when using this method. I'd be cautious about what you store here, but overall I really like the localStorage option for the right situation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply..

I am actually trying to load and store data with text boxes

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Use the text box as your input element as usual. When the form is submitted just use local storage instead of passing data to the server. You can also render your local storage data back into a text box in the view if you'd like. Are you having a specific problem?